# Showing images linked with corresponding KMZ in QGIS

Tags: qgis, image, kmz

I have the master KMZ with the images that are linked to its corresponding placemarks, I can see the images of KMZ in Google Earth, but while loading in QGIS, I can't see the images.

So, how can I see the images of individual KMZ in QGIS?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you give a link to the KMZ file?

Comment: I had tried to import the photos folder of the kml but that too it is not working

Comment: While loading the kmz file in qgis  only the points are in the layout, but while clicking on that I can't see the images

Answer (score 2):

One option:
Unzip the KMZ file using 7-Zip or another unzipping software that can read KMZ.
In QGIS, use the "Import geotagged photos" tool and import the folder of images that were unzipped from the KMZ.

A new point shapefile with a filename attribute of the corresponding photo in the images folder will be created, and you can use that to cross-reference the location of the photos with the images in the folder.